# How To Authorize an MVC Controller with an Admin authentication, While still being inside IdentityServer v4

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I have created an IdentityServer project and it works flowlessly for any grant types.
But I want to administrate Identity server using a dashboard. The dashboard will be hosted on the same Identity Server for doing the following purposes. It dynamically loads clients, api resources and scopes from my SQL Server. These are the roles for dashboard

1. Add/Edit/Delete OAuth Clients
2. Add/Edit/Delete OAuth APIResources
3. Add/Edit/Delete OAuth Scopes

I implemented it and so far everything is working fine.

Here's a screenshot of working example of my dashboard hosted on `"https://[IdentityServerBaseURL]/Administration"`.

[image]

What I want to achieve is - This dashboard holds sensitive auth configurations.

1. It should not be accessible by just going to the URL (Security Threat).
2. Only an Auth administrator who uses an admin credential like `'admin' & 'authserver@123'` can gain access to this dashboard.

While still being in Identity Server project, How can I implement authentication to allow only an admin user to this page (or Controller)?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net Core has some pretty flexible authorization capabilities. Check out this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0